# How to create a generic instance of PCL Feature class?

Tags: templates, eigen, point-cloud-library

I want to compute various features with PCL. My idea is to create a program that create the Feature based on what is given on the command-line (the name of the class and it's parameters), compute them and write them in a file.

Therefore I need a some code that create a "generic" Feature. PCL features are template classes. One must instantiate them with an input type (the type of the data you want to compute them on) and the output type. Input type is usually `pcl::PointCloud` so I don't think it's a problem. For output I use `Eigen::MatrixXf` as a "generic" output type.
However I have some strange errors.

I have written a minimal example (it uses some `typedef` in order to be easier to modify):

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/features/fpfh.h>

typedef pcl::PointXYZ  Input_T;
//#define USE_EIGEN
#ifdef USE_EIGEN
#warning "USING EIGEN"
typedef Eigen::MatrixXf Output_T;
#else
typedef pcl::PointNormal Output_T;
#endif

int main()
{
  pcl::Feature<Input_T, Output_T>* q = new pcl::NormalEstimation<Input_T, Output_T>;
}
```

If you compile it "as is" it should work. If you uncomment line 7 it won't work anymore.
The error given by GCC is:

```
tmp/test.cc:16:49: erreur: cannot convert ‘pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >*’ to ‘pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >*’ in initialization
```

I use PCL 1.6 with GCC 4.6.3 under Ubuntu 12.04.

Any idea of what is wrong?
I have asked the PCL user mailing list without success.

Comment: The strange thing is that it works with MatrixXd instead of MatrixXf. I think this is connected to some [pcl specific template specialisation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.5.1/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud_3_01_eigen_1_1_matrix_xf_01_4.html)

Comment: I can compile it with `MatrixXd` but cannot link: `[vtable for pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >]+0x1c): undefined reference to ``pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::computeFeature(pcl::PointCloud<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >&)'`. Moreover in this case I can't use [computeEigen](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_feature.html#ac6d3502c027c913891b17613aa29f8ab) which is the ultimate goal.

Comment: I have read the link you send but I don't get why this causes the error (except the fact that this I supposed to be for advanced users).